# How do I revert whatever setting in Visual Studio 2015 that has turned my whitespace brown?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've hit some form of key combination this afternoon and now in my Visual Studio code windows, whitespace is colored brown.  To be clear, I use the darker theme with the lighter text.  I mis-hit a series of keys and now all whitespace is brown, instead of deep-gray.

I am aware of the the the feature that shows white-space characters, as symbols which can be turned on from `Edit->Advanced->Show White Space`.  This is not the setting that has changed my display.

Does anyone know what feature does this and how to turn it back off?  Thank you.

Comment: You don't have the "Find" window open and have a white space in that do you?

Comment: Lol, ha!  That's it.  I must have hot-keyed it opened and didn't even notice.